# Setting a WPFDataGrid columnheader to a TextBlock

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with `AutoGenerateColumns=True`.

I want to set the `ColumnHeaders` to a `TextBlock` so the heading text can wrap.

I have:

```
Private Sub OnAutoGeneratingColumn(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs)
....
    Dim tb As New TextBlock
    tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
    tb.Text = SomeText
    e.Column.Header = tb
End Sub
```

In other code, I can see that the `ColumnHeader` is actualy a `TextBlock`, and doing

```
Dim sHeader as String = DirectCast(dgtc.Header, TextBlock).Text
```

returns SomeText back.

But, the Grid Does not display any text in the header!  If on the other hand I set

```
e.Column.Header = SomeText
```

The headings show OK.

What am I missing?

I know there are some answers for this on the site but I could not find any for AutoGenerateColumns = True.

Comment: I have tried your OnAutoGeneratingColumn code and it works fine. Maybe other header/textblock styles or templates take precedence?

Comment: @LPL Yes you are probably right.  Thanks for the confirmation of my approach.

Comment: Is there a reason why are you doing all of this in code instead of in XAML?  With the WPF DataGrid, there are a lot of XAML templating that can be done that will make most of this a bit easier and cleaner.